# conan install --build fails due to mismatching versions even after changing default

Tags: c++, linux, package, dependencies, conan

I am using conan to handle dependencies and I have already been able to compile and run the project by running individual steps like `source` and `build`.

I however want to be able to install and build in a single step, and for that purpose I do:

`conan install . -if build -s build_type=Debug --build`

In which case for some packages I get:

```
Compiler version specified in your conan profile: 10.3

  Compiler version detected in CMake: 9.3

  Please check your conan profile settings (conan profile show
  [default|your_profile_name])

  P.S.  You may set CONAN_DISABLE_CHECK_COMPILER CMake variable in order to
  disable this check.
```

Now I can change the profile settings to match the requested compiler settings, but then other, different, packages start complaining about mismatching compiler versions. i.e. some packages want version 9.3, others version 10.3, others version 9...

Considering the packages dependencies already link with my executable if I just run the build steps individually, I am not sure why I am getting this catch 22 behaviour.

I tried a suggestion in the comments by adding this to my `conanfile.py`

```py
def configure(self):
        # gcc compiler version
        defs = {}
        if self.settings.compiler == "gcc":
            defs["CMAKE_C_COMPILER"] = f"gcc-{self.settings.compiler.version}"
            defs["CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER"] = f"g++-{self.settings.compiler.version}"

        # configure cmake
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(defs = defs)

        return super().configure()
```

I get an exception.

Comment: You have to impose to Cmake which compiler should be used, based on your profile. Please, read https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/8872 , it's a similar question. About single step install build, you don't need to pass install folder, conan will use your conan cache directly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am a litle bit confused as to where the author of that comment is putting his CMAKE flag setting code.

I tried it in build but it doesn't seem to be working. I also tried making a `configure()` method and it doesn;t seem to do anything either.

Comment: I am also a little confused, if I don't specify the installation directory conan just creates all the pc files in the current directory, which pollutes the root of the project. i.e. if I do:

`conan install . -s build_type=Debug`

Comment: The author used the profile to set the environment variables. Take a look on the example from docs: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html#examples. Don't force your compiler by configure method, instead, update your profile, it's much safer.

Comment: The install folder is correct, if you don't specify an install folder, Conan will use your current directory. It's explained on docs: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html

Comment: Then I don't fully understadn this comment:

"About single step install build, you don't need to pass install folder, conan will use your conan cache directly."

: p

Comment: Usually you mix both cmake cache with conan generated files, like: `cd project/ && mkdir build/ && cd build/ && conan install .. -s build_type=Debug && cmake .. && cmake --build .` Basically you don't need an install folder.

Comment: I use meson, but that command seems more complicated than `conan install . -if build -s build_type=Debug --build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't tell CMake about the compiler you want to use, it will try to *discover* it in the `project(...)` call. If they don't match, a check performed by a Conan macro will fail.

Typically, if you want to use a compiler version different from the default you need to inform CMake about it. One of the most common ways to do it using Conan profiles is to add the `CC` and `CXX` variables to the profile itself.

```
[settings]
...
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=10.3
...


[env]
CC=/usr/bin/gcc-10
CXX=/usr/bin/g++-10
```

Conan will add these variables to the environment before calling the build system and most of them (CMake, Autotools,...) will take them into account.

This way, **you don't need to modify the `conanfile.py` file**.